# Added conditions to LinQ-query are not included

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Normally it should work and i saw on forum questions like this but for me it is very strange and the where conditions are not addes although they are executed.

Here is my code:

```
var query = context.infoes.Join(context.users, u => u.Id, a => a.Id, (u, a) => new { U = u, A = a }).
                    Where(j=>j.A.IA==true).
                    Where(j=>j.U.G==(int)model.G).
                    Where(j=>j.U.CI==model.CI);

if (MA != null)
{
    query.Where(j => j.U.BD < MD);
}

if (MIA != null)
{
    query.Where(j => j.U.BD > MIA);
}

query.Where(j => j.U.Id == 10);
int countResults = query.Count();
```

This last where i've just added to be sure, but it is not added either. So after the first line of code in intermidiate window i put query and i saw the sql, so i've let the code run and add the other where, but the query didn't change it still defined only the base conditions.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign the conditions back to query, like

```
query = query.Where(j => j.U.BD < MD);
```

Comment: Oh, omg sorry for this stupid question then :/ kinda didn't notice that.